# Modelbinding brakes on after adding html5 attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html, model-binding

I have a view and it uses TextBoxFor helper method to edit model. Like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { @class = "mybox" })%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)%>
</div>
```

So, Modelbinder works fine and I can edit and save my model.

When I add html5 attributes 'type' and 'step' like this

```
<div class="editor-field">
                <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { @class = "mybox",@type = "number", @step = "1" })%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)%>
</div>
```

I see beautiful numeric control instead of textbox, but modelbinding brakes and whenever I change my Property I recieve 0 in my model.Property on submit.

What's wrong with my code?

That's my simple model

```
public class Model
    {

        [DisplayName("Property")]
        public int Property
        {
            get;
            set;
        }           
    }
```

---

Nathan, my explanation of the problem is not precise here. Here [Ajax Form breaks after adding html5 attributes in Chrome/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084826/ajax-form-breaks-after-adding-html5-attributes-in-chrome-safari) is a better description and workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/asp-net-mvc-html5-toolkit/29

Based on your code, this works for me:

Controller:

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(Model model)
    {
        return Content(model.Property.ToString());
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    [DisplayName( "Property" )]
    public int Property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BindTest.Models.Model>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%using( Html.BeginForm( "index", "index" ) ){ %>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new {@class = "mybox", @type = "number", @step = "1"})%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)%>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" value="click Me">Click Me</button>

    <% } %>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click my submit button, the number selected in my numeric input control is received by the controller and output to the browser.

We'll need to see more code to be more helpful.

Comment: Thx, but I want to know what's wrong with my example. And third party libs are not the best way to solve this problem imo.

Comment: I've used that successfully before, thought something in his source might help you.

That said, I just tried your example and it works fine for me.  Can you supply your controller code?

Comment: Nathan, thans for your help - I've tried it your way and found that the problem that I have happens only with Chrome/Safari browsers. In IE/Firedox it's ok. The only thing that I've changed is the form - it's Ajax in my example

Comment: Nathan, so the problem in Chrome/Safari disappears when I change AjaxForm to HtmlForm. Any ideas?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. When I changed the example I posted above from Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm, it still works correctly.