# Ajax Form breaks after adding html5 attributes in Chrome/Safari

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, html, google-chrome, safari

Step by step description:

New Asp.Net MVC2 project

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Property 
    { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        return Content(model.Property.ToString());
    }
}
```

Index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVCTest.Models.TestModel>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")%>"></script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%using( Ajax.BeginForm( "index", "home", new AjaxOptions()
                                                {
                                                    HttpMethod = "Post",
                                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                    UpdateTargetId = "Result"
                                                } ) ){ %>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new {@type = "number", @step = "1"})%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)%>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" value="click Me">Click Me</button>

    <% } %>

    <div id="Result">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Given mvc application refuses to work properly in Chrome/Safari browsers - I receive 
`model.Property == 0` in my controller method on post.

When I remove html5 attributes, changing:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new {@type = "number", @step = "1"})%>
```

to

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property)%>
```

it works like expected.

So what's wrong with my ajax form with html5 attributes from Chrome/Safari's point of view? IE/FF browsers work fine in every case.

**Upd**

Resulting html from fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2011 07:16:19 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 890
Connection: Close


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1"><title>
    Index
</title></head>
    <body>
     <form action="/" method="post" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));" onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: &#39;Post&#39;, updateTargetId: &#39;SaveResultDiv&#39; });">
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="mybox" id="Property" name="Property" step="1" type="number" value="" />

        </div>

        <button type="submit" value="click Me">Click Me</button>

    </form>
    <div id="SaveResultDiv"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ajax request (Safari):

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:35636/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:35636
Referer: http://myapp/
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU
Origin: http://myapp
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest, XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 31
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

Just to compare - ajax request in IE:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:35636/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru
Referer: http://myapp/
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest, XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Host: 127.0.0.1:35636
Content-Length: 44
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

Property=555&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

Obviously requests in Chrome/Safari and IE/FF differ for some unknown reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the resulting HTML, and the AJAX call (use Fiddler).

Comment: could be a bug in the ASP.NET MVC JS. The HTML seems legit. What I would do is experiment with the HTML5 attributes (fewer, more, different ones), and try the same thing but with a normal non-AJAX form. One could also step into the ASP.NET MVC JS to see why the form field isn't picked up or why it isn't sent with the request.

Comment: bzlm, thanks for your support. Html Form works fine, trouble happens only in case of combination Ajax+Html5+Safari/Chrome. If it's asp.net mvc js bug, then why it's browser-dependent?

Comment: maybe simply because JS itself a browser-dependent, and it follows, then, that ASP.NET MVC JS would reap the same grapes of sorrow that all JS does. I'd like you to try this in ASP.NET MVC 3 with a brand new project that only contains minimal code to reproduce the problem. If you can't, try the same with MVC 2. If you can't reproduce there either, then there's something else interfering. If you *can* reproduce, send a bug report to Microsoft, and find a way to get the ASP.NET MVC team (who are on SO frequently) to look a this question for a swift resolve. (:

Comment: thanks for help, finally developed some workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developed some workaround - migrated to MVC3 , elabled UnobtrusiveJavaScript in web.config like this:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

then threw away references to MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, instead using these ones:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")%>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")%>"></script>
```

Solved the problem, but it looks like a bug for me and I would report it to MS.